# How do i checkout files in a directory non recursively in CVS

Tags: cvs, tortoisecvs

I want to checkout files of a directory from cvs server using cvs checkout command, but it is checking out files in recursive directories fashion,which i dont want.Please help me out.

For example i have following directory structure in cvs server.

dir1/abc 
dir1/xyz
dir1/xyz/a1/a11
dir1/xyz/a1/a12

and i want to checkout files which are in dir1 directory only.

Please help me out !!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the -l option to achieve this.

```
cvs checkout -l dir1
```

Cvs will not recurse into subdirectories.